# CSS Image auto width and height

Tags: css

I have a div which has image inside it. I want the image to have maximum height or width as the div but not exceed it. [Fiddle - Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/766ewje6/)

```
div.gcontainer{
    position: fixed;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
div.gcontainer img{
    position:relative;
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

Not getting it. What should I do?

Comment: you got a jfiddle? or something so we can view it?

Comment: You meant your fiddle to be http://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/766ewje6/1/ (wrong reference to the img in the original). Depending on the window size image should go with either full width or height and I think you'll need javascript to achieve that (easy but not a CSS solution). Alternatively you can use the image as background with `background-size: contain;` with `no-repeat` etc, but since they're slide images, not so sure if you wanna go that route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is image's container has fixed position with width/height of 100%, so it can take the whole page. You can instead put `.gcontainer` in a div with fixed position and with specified dimensions:

```css
#container {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
div.gcontainer {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
div.gcontainer img {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="gcontainer">
    <img src="http://www.keenthemes.com/preview/metronic/theme/assets/global/plugins/jcrop/demos/demo_files/image1.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What if I want the container to take up entire browsing window?

Comment: Well if that's what you want then image can take the whole page too, isn't that why you set max dimentions to 100%?

Answer (score 0):

in your image container set width or height (one only) to auto.

```
div.gcontainer img
{
position:relative;
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
```